# How to fix metallic teeth in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a really old picture with metallic teeth that I've been trying to colorize to look like normal teeth. Can someone point me in the right direction to fixing these? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use lower two teeth---- select with lasso or anything, ctrl+T and flip vertically, move up to upper teeth's position, warp to fit the shape. When transform is done, do some brightness&contrast adjustment, finally do some color blending with left/right teeth.

Comment: I've followed your suggestion up until the the point with color blending. How do I go about blending the colors? https://imgur.com/a/4D4ZlcD

Comment: @torrinew fastest way: create a blank layer, ctrl_alt_G to make it clipping to new teeth layer, change this blank layer's blending mode to color, use a 10%-flow brush, then hold alt key and get nearby teeth's color and brush it !

Comment: @torrinew Apparently your new teeth is too wide, when transforming new teeth layer, you could lower its transparency in the layers panel temporarily, in order to fit shape with original upper teeth.

Comment: Thanks for the transparency tip that really helped! I've fiddled with it more and blended it as best I could. It probably could use more work but I think it looks OK from a bit far now at least. Thank you so much! https://imgur.com/a/I8MOlXN

Comment: @torrinew you're welcome.....still too wide.